# I want to create a code that attacks a 2D image while rotating it 90 degrees

Tags: 2d

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if (PlayCharNum == 0):
if(time.time() - timeset >= 1.5):
timeset = time.time()
angle_sw = math.atan2(position[1]-(playerpos[1]+32),position[0]-(playerpos[0]+26)) - 
sw_loc = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360-angle_sw*57.29)
swpos1 = (playerpos[0]+3, playerpos[1]-playerrot.get_rect().height//2)
screen.blit(sw_loc, swpos1)
attack = 1
temp = 0.5
```

I would like to create a code that attacks the bullet picture by rotating it 90 degrees when the space bar is pressed.

bullet The picture appears briefly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.